# Attributes null despite Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to use an object in several controllers using Depedency Injection.
But the variables of the object are always null.

The class whose attributes I would like to use in several classes:

```
public class Info
{
    public string DriveId {get; set;}
    public string ItemId {get; set;}
    public int SubscriptionTime {get; set;}
    public string PdfItemId {get; set;}
}
```

Controller class 1:

```
    //...
    private Info info;

    public SubscriptionController(Info info)
    {
        this.Info = info;
    }

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(string driveId, string itemId, string pdfItemId, int subscriptionTime)
  {
           //......
           Info = new Info{DriveId = driveId, ItemId = itemId, 
           SubscriptionTime = subscriptionTime, PdfItemId = pdfItemId}; //Here the class (Info) is instantiated:
          //......
   }
```

Configuartion in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
            //....
            services.AddScoped<IFileService, FileService>(); //Database service class: it runs without problems
            services.AddScoped<Info>(); //But this scope somehow causes me problems.
            //...
    }
```

And in another controller I need the instance (from Info) and according to debugger and console it is null.
Controller class 2:

```
   //...
 private Info info;

 public OtherController(Info info)
      {
          this.Info = info;
      }

  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult GetActionResult()
       {
         Console.WriteLine(info.DriveId);
         //... 
        }
```

Which beginner's mistake have I made ?

Comment: Of course its values are always null, you don't set any values during registration

Comment: This is a bit confusing, I already set the values (from the info class) in controller class 1.I have changed the class name, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddScoped`, like you did, registers the service with a scoped lifetime, the lifetime of a single request. Next time you make a request, another instance of Info will be injected into the Controller(s).

`AddSingleton` would register a singleton (only one instance) for the whole application. But then your instance of `Info` would be shared across all requests for as long as the application lives. So every user of the application would share the same instance of `Info` each time they made a request.

However, although I don't know the nature of your application, something is very odd in what you are trying to achieve here: setting the values for something that was injected via dependency injection with Controller input is not how things usually are done.

Comment: I would like to make certain values (id, time, etc.) accessible to other controllers and have therefore packed them into an object and would like to make this object available to other controllers. Do you have any other ideas ? :-)

Comment: What if a user_1 sets the values and then a second user, user_2, accesses the Controllers? Should user_2 be able to get the same values that user_1 "saved"? I'd personally persist those values, in something like a database, in the first Controller, and retrieve them in the other Controllers.

Comment: Then if you persist the data you can even segregate it by user. So user_1 will have his values, user_2 will have their own. Having data live as part of the server's life-cycle is (almost always) a bad idea.